# Is it more expensive to use too many static variables instead of ordinary variables? If yes, then how?

Tags: c++

I want to know that is it really costly to implement too many static variables instead of ordinary variables? If yes, then please provide some examples

Comment: Write your code correct first. Also "ordinary" variables is too vague. Basic data types on the stack are very fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be. It can lead to cache misses, because the memory where static variables are stored are typically well separated from the other variables/code you are accessing. If you find yourself writing `static const` outside of member variables, give yourself a slap and take that `static` out (sorry, massive, pet hate).

But, as the [other Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25203514/) points out: you shouldn't worry about it as a performance issue until you've checked and found it is. It's much more of a design concern.

Comment: "other Jack" haha

Answer (score 2):

The performance cost is negligible until proven, so you shouldn't consider it as a performance issue. You should consider it as a design issue.

A `static` variable fulfils a different purpose compared to instance variables or local variables. If you need to use many of them maybe you can encapsulate them inside objects.

Answer (score -1):

With older/simpler target platforms you may even gain. Compared to heap or stack access the instructions generated for static may be simpler, avoiding one level of indirection.